# fb:request-form in iframe redirects away from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, fbrequest-form

I have an `<fb:requestform>` in an iFrame Facebook app.  I have set target="_parent", so that the callback will target the parent iFrame and not itself, which seems to work as expected.  But, instead of my desired file loading, I get redirected to my server.  Checking the response of the requestform's POST in Firebug revealed this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=***&v=1.0&req_perms=&next=http%3A%2F%2F***";
</script>
```

I have already had this same problem when sending jQuery AJAX requests to update various elements in an iFrame.  I solved the problem by making sure my headers contain `P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"`.  That is indeed set for this call as well (can be seen clearly in Firebug), but I still get redirected to facebook.com/login.php.

Comment: Check what is being sent when you submit that form.  Do the proper Facebook cookies go with it?  That redirect you're getting is definitely a result of `$facebook->require_login()` failing to validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up working around this problem rather than solving it.  Instead of using require_login() on most of my pages, I store the user's Facebook ID and their session key in session variables and use those to "reinstantiate" the user (using $facebook->set_user()) on subsequent page calls.